# Как правильнее собирать модуль ядра linux под несколько разных дистрибутивов

Tags: linux, ядро

Опишу ситуацию - у меня есть модуль ядра, который нужно собрать под несколько разных дистрибутивов с разными ядрами.
Хотелось бы узнать как лучше и правильнее это делать. Возможно, что есть какая-нибудь документация.

Сейчас вижу 3 разных варианта:

1. Сборка модулей на одной системе, расположив заговочные файлы ядра в разных папках.
2. Сборка модулей на одной системе, используя chroot для каждого дистрибутива.
3. Сборка на нескольких системах - для каждого дистрибутива будет система

Вариант 1 - возникли проблемы со сборкой для Альт Линукс СП 10 - т.к. там используется objtool, который зависит от libc собранного для этого дистрибутива.

Вариант 2 - еще не пробовал

Вариант 3 - кажется очень затратным по ресурсам и времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С таким подходом ЧРУТИТЬСЯ точно надо. Но в той же Ubuntu больше 300 версий ядра в одном релизе. Я бы рекомендовал завязаться на dkms.